# How to connect to a SSH session that was backgrounded with -f -N?

Tags: linux, ssh, unix, shell, ssh-tunnel

I'm doing some work where I need to pivot off a machine using proxychains so I'm connecting to a system and binding a local port like so...

```
ssh -f -N -D 9000 user@host.com
```

… which returns me back to my command prompt after opening the connection. I can then use something like proxychains to run commands through `host.com`.

My question is: How can I connect/interact with that same session so I can get a remote shell on host.com? The way I'm doing it now is opening up another ssh session with a simple `ssh user@host.com`, but I'm thinking there has to be a way to just utilize that first session that I opened.

Answer (score 11):

If it wasn't created with multiplex enabled, you cannot.

**Next time,** start the background session like this:

```
ssh -f -N -M -S ~/.ssh/S.user@host.com -D 9000 user@host.com
```

Here `-M` enables multiplex master mode, and `-S` sets the socket path.

Now you can use `ssh -S ~/.ssh/S.user@host.com dummyhost` to open a second session over the same connection. It's possible to control the master by giving `-O exit`, `-O check`, and various other options. (Sadly, `-O forward` is a very recent addition.)

To make this automatic, you can use the following options in `.ssh/config`:

```
Host *
    ControlPath ~/.ssh/S.%l.%r@%h:%p
    ControlMaster auto
    ControlPersist 10m
```

Setting `ControlPath` means you do not need to specify `-S` every time.

Setting `ControlMaster auto` means that every new connection will automatically continue in background as a multiplex master. (Without it, you can still start new masters with `ssh -fNM host`).

Setting `ControlPersist 10m` means that the automatic masters will stick around for 10 minutes when they don't have any active sessions. (This is a recently added option.)

Note that batch transfers over a multiplex connection will cause interactive sessions to become really slow...

Answer (score 0):

Leave off the -f (Background SSH) and the -N (Do not execute remote command) parameters, so use

```
ssh -D 9000 user@host.com
```

Comment: This is going to start another new SSH session which will also try to do port-forwarding to the local machine's port `9000`. It will give a warning about being unable to bind to port 9000 if there is already another SSH session open which I believe is what the OP's use case looks like.